# Sitecore 8: SEO URLs

Tags: sitecore

I would like to be able to:

Name *items* with any or all of the following:

- letter *(upper or lowercase)*
- any number
- spaces

I have added the following two lines to the `<encodeNameReplacements>` node:

```xml
<replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-"/>
<replace mode="on" find="_" replaceWith="-" />
```

I have updated the  to have the following value:

```
\/:?&quot;&lt;&gt;|[]-_
```

Do I need to update the `<setting name="ItemNameValidation">` too?

What would be the correct regex to use for the above scenario?   I tried tinkering with it, and well let's just say something isn't right.

Comment: Those encodename replacements will not work is you have an item name with both spaces and underscores (although I can see you have disallowed them). I wrote a blog post you may find helpful: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/seo-friendly-urls-in-sitecore-prevention-is-better-than-cure/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes I would update the `ItemNameValidation` setting.
I think this pattern should meet your requirements:

`^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$`

It specifies that the string should be composed of one or more of any of the following:

- A-Z
- a-z
- 0-9
- [Space]

Just in case there's some confusion, `encodeNameReplacements` is not relevant to item naming. It's for the generation of URL's